# Including a Django app's url.py is resulting in a 404

Tags: python, django, url-routing, http-status-code-404, django-urls

I have the following code in the urls.py in mysite project.

**/mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^gallery/$', include('mysite.gallery.urls')),
)
```

This results in a 404 page when I try to access a url set in gallery/urls.py.

**/mysite/gallery/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
urlpatterns = patterns('',  
    (r'^gallery/browse/$', 'mysite.gallery.views.browse'),
    (r'^gallery/photo/$', 'mysite.gallery.views.photo'),
)
```

**404 error**

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^gallery/$
The current URL, gallery/browse/, didn't match any of these.
```

Also, the site is hosted on a media temple (dv) server and using mod_wsgi

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove the `$` from the regex of main `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^gallery/', include('mysite.gallery.urls')),
)
```

You don't need `gallery` in the included Urlconf.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',  
    (r'^browse/$', 'mysite.gallery.views.browse'),
    (r'^photo/$', 'mysite.gallery.views.photo'),
)
```

Read the [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) for more information

> Note that the regular expressions in this example don't have a `$` (end-of-string match character) but do include a trailing slash. Whenever Django encounters `include()`, it chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and **sends the remaining string** to the included URLconf for further processing.